# Loop when I don't want it to

Tags: python-3.x

So I wrote a program that is supposed to simulate a game of Pig, where people roll dice until 100 points. The code is fine until it switches from the player to the computer, where the computer just puts it into a loop with no variation and I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Any help is appreciated!

```
import random

def comp_roll():
    CompScore = 0
    die1 = random.randint (1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint (1, 6)
    BothDice = die1 + die2
    print("Rolled {} and {}" .format(die1, die2))
    print("Computer earned", BothDice, "points.")


def comp():
    CompScore = 0
    die1 = random.randint (1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint (1, 6)
    BothDice = die1 + die2
    while CompScore < 100 :
        if die1 == 1 and die2 != 1 :
            print("Rolled {} and {}" .format(die1, die2))
            print ("Computer's turn is over!")
            input("Please click enter to continue...")
            dice()
        elif die1 != 1 and die2 ==1 :
           print("Rolled {} and {}" .format(die1, die2))
           print ("Computer's turn is over!")
           input("Please click enter to continue...")
           dice()
       elif die1 != 1 and die2 != 1:
           CompScore = CompScore + BothDice
           print("Rolled {} and {}" .format(die1, die2))
           print("Computer earned", BothDice, "points!")
           input("Please click enter to continue...")
       elif die1 ==1 and die2 ==1 :
           CompScore = PlayerScore + 25
           print("Computer rolled double 1 and earned 25 points.")
           print("Computer score is now ", CompScore)
           input("Please click enter to continue...")
       if CompScore >= 100:
          print("You lose!")
          input("click enter to exit program.")
          exit()

def dice():
   PlayerScore = 0
   CompScore = 0
   die1 = random.randint (1, 6)
   die2 = random.randint (1, 6)
   BothDice = die1 + die2
   print("you rolled a", die1, "and", die2)
   while PlayerScore <100 :
       if die1 == 1 and die2 != 1 :
           print("you rolled a", die1, "and", die2)
           print ("your turn is over!")
           input("Please click enter to continue...")
           comp()
       elif die1 != 1 and die2 ==1 :
           print("you rolled a", die1, "and", die2)
           print ("your turn is over!")
           input("Please click enter to continue...")
           comp()
       elif die1 != 1 and die2 != 1:
           PlayerScore = PlayerScore +BothDice
           print("You earned", BothDice, "points!")
           print ("Your total is now ", PlayerScore)
           reply = str(input("Would you like to roll again? 'y' or 'n'"))
           if reply == 'y' :
               die1 = random.randint (1, 6)
               die2 = random.randint (1, 6)
               BothDice = die1 + die2
               print("you rolled a", die1, "and", die2)

           elif reply == 'n':
                while CompScore < 100 :
                   if die1 == 1 and die2 != 1 :
                    print("Rolled {} and {}" .format(die1, die2))
                    print ("Computer's turn is over!")
                    input("Please click enter to continue...")
                    return
                elif die1 != 1 and die2 ==1 :
                    print("Rolled {} and {}" .format(die1, die2))
                    print ("Computer's turn is over!")
                    input("Please click enter to continue...")
                    return
                elif die1 != 1 and die2 != 1:
                    CompScore = CompScore + BothDice
                    print("Computer earned", BothDice, "points!")
                    input("Please click enter to continue...")
                    return
                elif die1 ==1 and die2 ==1 :
                    CompScore = PlayerScore + 25
                    print("Computer rolled double 1 and earned 25 points.")
                    print("Computer score is now ", CompScore)
                    input("Please click enter to continue...")
                    return
                if CompScore >= 100:
                    print("You lose!")
                    input("click enter to exit program.")
                    exit()
    elif die1 ==1 and die2 ==1 :
        PlayerScore = PlayerScore + 25
        print("You rolled double 1 and earned 25 points.")
        print("Your total score is now ", PlayerScore)
        input("Please click enter to continue...")
        roll()
    if PlayerScore == 100 :
        print("You win!")
        break
    elif CompScore == 100:
        print("You lose!")
        break
dice()
```

Comment: You have some severely messed up indentation @Will, you may want to fix that first.

Comment: I am trying to fix it as we speak.

Comment: I am not trying to be rude in this but @Will you code not only has indentation, formatting, using a comma rather than a plus when in a `print()` statement, adding integers to strings, but some serious logic issues. I would suggest to start form the ground up, this is not meant as a discouragement because the code you wrote has plenty of potential the logic of it just needs to be refined a bit more. Here is the code where all the issues have been fixed: http://dpaste.com/18BKFJA(I know I am not supposed to link off site, just understand that I have no room).

Comment: @Mr.Zeus Thank you so much! I've just started out coding so I don't know much about things.

Comment: Your welcome @Will all of us were where you were at one time or another. Just @ mention me in the question's comments if you need anything!